# My Apache and Mysql is not starting in xampp

Tags: mysql, apache, xampp

I am getting an error while starting apache and MySQL in xampp.
Following is the error I am getting:

[image]

I've tried changing port number in apache 80 to 8080 and 443 to 4433 but it is not working.

I've removed my old OS and installed new OS erasing all data then I installed xampp again but I am getting the same error in xampp.

Please, give me some solution to this problem.

result of following command `netstat -aon | findstr :80` is

[image]

Comment: Is this running on Windows or Linux

Comment: It is running in windows 10 version 2004

Comment: Then take a look at the Windows Event Viewer. Check the "Windows Logs -> Applications" section for error message from Apache and/or MySQL

Comment: There is no error available about Apache and/or MySQL

Comment: That seems a little odd :(

Comment: What should I do?

Comment: Run `netstat -aon | findstr :80` from a terminal windows and edit the results into your question (not in a comment)

Comment: Well according to that, nothing is using port 80  or 8080 so its not a blocked port

Comment: Privilages are unlikely on Windows unless you have a really wierd Windows setup

Comment: Which leaves missing dependancies. Odd that there are no error message in the event log

Comment: I didn't change anything in my windows settings after installing it again.